# saving a char pointer on a file with c++

Tags: c++, file, pointers

Hi I'm having trouble with a program which receives a text string provided by the user and does 3 things:

1. Convert all vowels to capital letters, print the new text and also print the number of vowels converted.
2. Save the new text into a file.
3. Print the converted text character by character.

Heres the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char *ptrQuote[80], int nvocals);
void save(char *ptrQuote[80]);
void print(char *ptrQuote[80]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char  quote[80];
    char *ptrQuote[80];
    int nvocals= 0;
    printf("Enter your quote :\n");
    scanf("%s", &quote);
    for(int i= 0; i<80; i++)
    {
        ptrQuote[i]= &quote[i];
    }
    convert(ptrQuote, nvocals);
    save(ptrQuote);
    print(ptrQuote);
    return 0;
}

void convert(char *ptrQuote[80], int nvocals)
{
    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
    {
        if(*ptrQuote[i]=='a')
        {
            *ptrQuote[i]='A';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(*ptrQuote[i]=='e')
        {
            *ptrQuote[i]='E';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(*ptrQuote[i]=='i')
        {
            *ptrQuote[i]='I';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(*ptrQuote[i]=='o')
        {
            *ptrQuote[i]='O';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(*ptrQuote[i]=='u')
        {
            *ptrQuote[i]='U';
            nvocals ++;
        }

    }

    printf("%s\n", *ptrQuote);
    printf("Number of vocals: %d\n", nvocals);
}

void save(char *ptrQuote[80])
{
    FILE *quote;
    quote= fopen("quote.txt", "w");
    fwrite(&ptrQuote[80], sizeof(*ptrQuote), 1, quote);
    fclose(quote);
}

void print(char *ptrQuote[80])
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(*ptrQuote); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", *ptrQuote[i]);
    }
}
```

The first function works properly but when it comes to the save and print functions it saves and prints the quote incomplete. As you can see I'm working with pointers. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: There is literally no C++ code in this program. Can this be re-tagged as C or were you intending to do C++?

Comment: you could stop working with pointers and use strings instead

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `ptrQuote`. It just appears to point to each individual character.

Comment: One problem is that `char *ptrQuote[80];` is 80 pointers to individual character, not at all something like a string. I can't figure out how to write that to a file either. (I can also see a deleted answer from someone else who attempted but failed.) You should probably start with a `std::string` and skip the char arrays and pointers.

Comment: its an school exercise so i have to do it exclusively with pointers

Comment: Then perhaps you should use 1 pointer that you increment over the array and not 80 pointers. (You should note that some of us trying to answer have been doing this for 20-30 year, and we cannot figure out the `ptrQuote`. You are trying **way** too hard :-)

Comment: If your teacher really insists on using a pointer, then my advise is this: Write the code without using any pointer but a `std::string myString` and then somewhere in the code you add a single line: `std::string* getHappyWithThisPointer = &myString`. Anything else is nonsense.

Comment: hm sorry I overread the "exclusively", sounds like real torturing with no benefit

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Instead of using 80 pointers (maybe a *little* overboard) for your code, just use one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char ptrQuote[80], int nvocals);
void save(char ptrQuote[80]);
void print(char ptrQuote[80]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char  quote[80];
    int nvocals = 0;
    printf("Enter your quote :\n");
    scanf("%s", &quote);
    convert(quote, nvocals);
    save(quote);
    print(quote);
    return 0;
}

void convert(char ptrQuote[80], int nvocals)
{
    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
    {
        if(ptrQuote[i]=='a')
        {
            ptrQuote[i]='A';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(ptrQuote[i]=='e')
        {
            ptrQuote[i]='E';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(ptrQuote[i]=='i')
        {
            ptrQuote[i]='I';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(ptrQuote[i]=='o')
        {
            ptrQuote[i]='O';
            nvocals ++;
        }

        if(ptrQuote[i]=='u')
        {
            ptrQuote[i]='U';
            nvocals ++;
        }

    }

    printf("%s\n", ptrQuote);
    printf("Number of vocals: %d\n", nvocals);
}

void save(char ptrQuote[80])
{
    FILE *quote;
    quote = fopen("quote.txt", "w");
    fwrite(ptrQuote, sizeof(*ptrQuote), 1, quote);
    fclose(quote);
}

void print(char ptrQuote[80])
{
    /* no need for loop here anymore */
    printf("%s\n", ptrQuote);
}
```

You also would be able to print to the file (using your method) with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i)
    fputc(*ptrQuote[i], quote);
```